# Angular CLI tests and enums

Tags: angular, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I am struggeling with Angular CLI's test framework and enum types. I am creating an enum like this (in someenum.ts):

```
const enum SomeEnum {
  Val0,
  Val1
}
```

And using it like this (in app.component.ts):

```
private someEnum = SomeEnum.Val0;
```

If I run this code using `ng serve` it runs ok, and the js generated defines it as:

```
this.someEnum = 0 /* Val0 */;
```

which is how it should be.

However, when I try to execute tests using `ng test` it fails with the compiler error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(10,14): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'SomeEnum'.
```

I think that the issue is something with the typescript configuration for test environment, but I can't figure it out, does someone have a good explanation of this?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.
You can fix it by exporting your enums.
For example:

***languageEnums.ts***

```
export const enum Languages {
  ENGLISH = "en-US",
  SWEDISH = "sv-SE"
}
```

***app.component.ts***

```
import { Languages } from '../assets/constants';

...

private language = Languages.ENGLISH;
```

I created a new `constants` folder in the `assets` folder which contains all the enums.
**One enum per file!**
You don't need to import them into the `app.module.ts` or the `.spec` files.

After that the errors where fixed.